# Replace characters in string while keeping varying sequence of numbers unchanged using sed

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have a string that holds characters as well as numbers, e.g.

```
one0.1231two,
```

and I'd like to replace *one* and *two* by a new sequence of characters

```
three0.1231four,
```

while keeping the numbers in between unchanged. However, while the two substrings *one* and *two* always remain the same, the sequence of number in between may vary in its length; so, for instance,

```
one0.000230002two, one1293.02two, or one42two
```

may occur. So far, I have only managed to do this replacement for a fixed numbers of digits using sed and regular expressions.

Only occurences of *one* and *two* around number as shown above should be replaced. All other occurences must stay the same.

Comment: Why does the intermediate string matter at all? why can't you just globally replace the old sequences with the new ones ex. `sed -e 's/one/three/g' -e 's/two/four/g'`?

Comment: Good point. I forgot  to mention that there may be other occurrences  of 'one' and 'two'  (without numbers) in the same file at variable positions that should not be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
sed 's/one\([[:digit:].]*\)two/three\1four/g'
```

The `\(...\)` *captures* was is matched within (here a sequence of 0 or more decimal digits or period) so it can be referred to as `\1` in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following `sed` substitution:

```
$ s="one0.000230002two, one1293.02two, or one42two "
$ sed -E 's/([^ 0-9]+)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)([^ 0-9,]+)/three\2four/g' <<<"$s"
three0.000230002four, three1293.02four, or three42four
```

Comment: Excellent! Tank you very much.